# file_put_contents(xxx.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am using `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` to create my pdf documents. I've created a function in the controller to create the pfd. But now I want to save the pdf.

```
 $myData = array('data' => $data);

 if (!empty($data)){

   // Send data to the view using loadView function of PDF facade
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $myData);

   // If you want to store the generated pdf to the server then you can use the 
   store function

   // Finally, you can download the file using download functio
   $pdf->save(storage_path('invoices\INV'.$year.Auth::user()->lab_id.'.pdf'));

   return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
 }
```

However now I get the error message

> `file_put_contents(C:\laragon\www\WebPTS\storage\invoices\INV201846.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Please assist.

Comment: Make sure ```C:\laragon\www\WebPTS\storage\invoices\``` exists before calling ```storage_path```.

Comment: I have created the folder. This is the first I have done. but my storage path is not WepPTS\storage... in filesystem.pfp `  'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ], `

Comment: I don't know your frameworks and libraries, but the error says it pretty clearly where it tries to store the PDF. You may also try escaping the ```\``` or use ```/``` instead.

Comment: I followed [link ]https://appdividend.com/2017/05/08/generate-pdf-blade-laravel-5-4/ it worked perfect. I just now want to save this

Comment: On my Localhost there is no problem saving the file. But I moved this to my weserver and now I get the error again. The directory was created on the webserver

Comment: Is the access for e.g. `www-data` defined properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m,anaged to get a document to load these files on Dropbox. https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-dropbox-api-file-upload-example-using-league-flysystem-dropbox-packageexample.html